# 1 to many select and concat

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

```
[customer]
id
name

[customer_photo]
id
customer_id
photo
```

I want to select all customers and their photos.

This query is doing it, but getting only users who have at least one photo:

```
SELECT customer.id, name, GROUP_CONCAT(cp.photo) as photos 
FROM customer 
JOIN customer_photo cp ON cp.customer_id = customer.id 
GROUP BY customer.id
```

I want to get all users, even if they don't have a photo.

Comment: then use left join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just by adding the LEFT join

```
SELECT customer.id, name, GROUP_CONCAT(cp.photo) as photos 
FROM customer 
LEFT JOIN customer_photo cp ON cp.customer_id = customer.id 
GROUP BY customer.id
```